# Apache CXF mustUnderstand boolean vs integer

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, cxf

I am working on a soap 1.1 service with Apache CXF 3.1.12 (with springboot)

I am trying to understand how I can coerce it into generating the mustUnderstand header as an integer (0|1) instead of boolean (true|false). See the incorrect document below. From what I understand, in soap 1.1 the true/false is not acceptable. Regardless, my clients do not like it and I do not have control over them.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="true">http://...</a:Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
     ...
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is a WSDL-first service and there is no mention of the SOAP 1.2 namespace in the WSDL. My package info is:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://...", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

and my endpoint is created with:

```
EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus,
                 new MyClass(), SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING);
```

I modify the mustUnderstand header in an AbstractSoapInterceptor at Phase.WRITE with hdr->setMustUnderstand(true), yet it still goes out as a boolean.

There is an old issue in JIRA about this, and is marked as fixed a long time ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2213?jql=text%20~%20%22mustUnderstand%22

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by forcing the response to be a SOAP 1.1 response in the interceptor, via:

```
final SoapVersion soap11 = Soap11.getInstance();
message.setVersion(soap11);
```

I doubt this is the correct way, I am not sure why it insists in thinking it's not a SOAP 1.1 message. But this at least fixed the specific issue above, and will allow me to proceed until I find the correct way.